# Using webpack with Rails asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, asset-pipeline, react-rails

I am using webpack with rails and sprockets. React is added through the gem react-rails. I keep getting the error

```
greet.self-c872e41….js?body=1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined(anonymous function)
main.self-8ac2c1a….js?body=1:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

So the fact that is it still reading from my greet file **app/assets/javascripts/components/main.jsx** and **greet.jsx** seems to be a problem to me, from what I understand with webpack is you want it to read from the exported bundle.js file.

My rails view looks like this:
**app/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<div id="react"></div>
<%= react_component("Main") %>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/components/main.jsx**

```
import Greet from './greet'

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Greet />
    )
  }
}
```

**app/assets/javascripts/components/greet.jsx**

```
export default class Greet extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h2>Hello There</h2>
  }
}
```

My Webpack file looks like this: **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./app/assets/javascripts/components/main.jsx",

  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/app/assets/javascripts",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: { presets:['es2015', 'react'] }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

And my **app/assets/javacsripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .
```

If I remove the import and export calls it works fine, but the tutorial i'm following uses them. When I remove the **components** directory, and only require the **bundle.js** file, I get the error from react-rails.

```
Main is not defined
```

I'm at a loss at how to get the calls import and export to be recognized. I know it's something about ES6, but I thought webpack was suppose to solve that.

greet.jsx, main.jsx, and bundle.js are all being called in my network tab on my browser.

Comment: Hi Chase, I think this fits your original goal quite well https://github.com/gauravtiwari/webpack_on_rails let me know what you think about it.

Comment: This also looks interesting: http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html

Comment: Awesome, giving both of those a try

Comment: Hey @ruevaughn any luck with those two links?